# GridView Itemtemplate fails to load viewstate if template has no white space

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Okay, this is a weird one.  I noticed some of our asp.net pages were ridiculously large given what they were (search dialogs and the like), and I noticed a few things:
a) that a lot of the rendered html was whitespace introduced with indentation on the templates (tab = 4 spaces, lots of indenting around the various controls)

b) We had a bunch of fixed display strings being put in asp:Labels with viewstate for no apparent reason.

So I set about to tighten some of this up.  Worked well, cut 1/3 off the page size.  But then when I was testing, I found a weird "Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request" exception when I hit the search button a second time without changing anything.  I finally tracked it down to a seemingly innocuous change and it still puzzles me why it made any difference.

We had a GridView template with a column containing

```
<itemtemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="IsRetired" Text='<%# GetRetiredStatusString( (bool)Eval("IsRetired") ) %>' />
</itemtemplate>
```

No error.  I replaced it with

```
<itemtemplate><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# GetRetiredStatusString( (bool)Eval("IsRetired") ) %>' /></itemtemplate>
```

And we started getting the viewstate error implying that we're screwing with the control tree on post back.  I went back and forth with different incantations and found

```
<itemtemplate>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# GetRetiredStatusString( (bool)Eval("IsRetired") ) %>' />
</itemtemplate>
```

works, but

```
<itemtemplate><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# GetRetiredStatusString( (bool)Eval("IsRetired") ) %>' />
</itemtemplate>
```

Doesn't.  So when I'm using a Literal, unless I have the leading whitespace in the template, it thinks I'm mucking with the control tree.

Does this make sense to anybody?

Thx.